# How to sum up the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following summation arises is a Bayesian model where Beta distribution is used as the prior for Negative Binomial distribution. The summation is used to assess the risk of the resulting estimator. However, to this stage it is only a pure mathematical problem. My question is how to find the following sum, please? Thank you!

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{(n+7)^2(n+8)} (1-\theta)^{n-2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: $(x-1)/(x+7)=1-(8/(x+7))$. $(1-\theta)^{x-2}=(1-\theta)^{-9}(1-\theta)^{x+7}$. $\sum u^r/r$ is a logarithm.

Comment: I don't quite understand why some are voting to close...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Have you ever read some kind of how-to-ask page on the site?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut This summation is from a negative binomial(r=2, p=1-$\theta$) with beta(4,3) as prior. I found the posterior distribution of $\theta$ as beta(6, $x$+1) and the posterior mean is $6/(x+7)$. But I could not calculate the Bayes Risk for this estimator which involves the above sum. Do you know any way to find the Bayes Risk without using this summation, please? Thank you!

Comment: You edited the problem in such a way that my earlier comment no longer applies. But just split that rational function of $n$ into partial fractions, then my comment will get you halfway there. The other half is trickier, at first sight it looks to me that it might involve a dilogarithm.

Comment: Yes, you get a dilogarithm.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Could you provide a bit more detail, please? I never heard about this kind of things. Thank you!

Comment: I was writing an answer, but thanks to question close, I won't be able to give it to you. You have to develop in partial fraction to get $${{\left(n-1\right)\,\left(n+1\right)}\over{\left(n+7\right)^2\,
 \left(n+8\right)}}={{63}\over{n+8}}-{{62}\over{n+7}}+{{48}\over{\left(n+7\right)^2}}$$ Then compute the sum for each one, changing indices to have $n$ in denominator, and this will give you two logarithms (minus the first terms of the log series, which are missing), **and** a series which is really a [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html), that is a series in $x^n/n^2

Comment: Regarding the dilogarithm, if you need numerical computations of your series, it's available in many software packages, for example [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Dilogarithm.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
$${{\left(n-1\right)\,\left(n+1\right)}\over{\left(n+7\right)^2\,
 \left(n+8\right)}}={{63}\over{n+8}}-{{62}\over{n+7}}+{{48}\over{\left(n+7\right)^2}}$$

Thus, with $\xi=1-\theta$

$$f(\theta)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{(n+7)^2(n+8)} (1-\theta)^{n-2}\\=
63 \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(1-\theta)^{n-2}}{n+8}
-62\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(1-\theta)^{n-2}}{n+7}
+48 \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(1-\theta)^{n-2}}{(n+7)^2}
\\=
63 \frac{1}{\xi^{10}} \sum_{n=10}^\infty \frac{\xi^{n}}{n}
-62 \frac{1}{\xi^{9}} \sum_{n=9}^\infty \frac{\xi^{n}}{n}
+48 \frac{1}{\xi^{9}} \sum_{n=9}^\infty \frac{\xi^{n}}{n^2}
$$

And

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\xi^n}{n}=-\log (1-\xi)=-\log \theta$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\xi^n}{n^2}=\mathrm{Li_2}(\xi)$$

Where $\mathrm{Li_2}$ is the [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html).

Therefore,

$$f(\theta)=-63\frac{\log \theta}{(1-\theta)^{10}}+62\frac{\log \theta}{(1-\theta)^{9}}+48\frac{\mathrm{Li_2}(\theta)}{(1-\theta)^{9}}-g(\theta)$$

With

$$g(\theta)=63 \sum_{n=1}^{9} \frac{(1-\theta)^{n-10}}{n}
-62  \sum_{n=1}^{8} \frac{(1-\theta)^{n-9}}{n}
+48  \sum_{n=1}^{8} \frac{(1-\theta)^{n-9}}{n^2}$$